# In order to generate all combinations of 1's and 0's we use a simple binary table. How can I easily create this binary table in an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example the binary table for 3 bit:

```
0 0 0

0 0 1

0 1 0

1 1 1

1 0 0 

1 0 1
```

And I want to store this into an n*n*2 array so it would be:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
1 0 0 
1 0 1
```

Comment: `n*n*2`? What does that even mean here? What is `n`? Why are you making a 3D table?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I mean the array will be 1D array of size N*N*2, for example in my case - 3*3*2 = 18

Comment: You want incomplete tables? For three bits, there are 8 possible outputs (your example is missing `011` and `110`, which is why you only counted six).

Comment: Yeah, I wrote one in just Python, it seems like that might be what you're looking for.  It features even the ones not listed though.  (I really don't know what pattern you want to exclude, if any).

Answer (score 4):

For generating the combinations automatically, you can use itertools.product standard library, which generates all possible combinations of the different sequences which are supplied, i. e. the cartesian product across the input iterables. The repeat argument comes in handy as all of our sequences here are identical ranges.

```
from itertools import product
x = [i for i in product(range(2), repeat=3)]
```

Now if we want an array instead a list of tuples from that, we can just pass this to numpy.array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(x)

# [[0 0 0]
# [0 0 1]
# [0 1 0]
# [0 1 1]
# [1 0 0]
# [1 0 1]
# [1 1 0]
# [1 1 1]]
```

If you want all elements in a single list, so you could index them with a single index, you could chain the iterable:

```
from itertools import chain, product
x = list(chain.from_iterable(product(range(2), repeat=3)))

result: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: @jondoe itertools.product is a handy function that gives you the cartesian product of input iterables.

Comment: one more question, how do I store this in array element by element, say a[0] = 0 and a[1] = 0 etc etc.

Comment: @jondoe I added how to do that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Most people would expect 2^n x n as in

```
np.c_[tuple(i.ravel() for i in np.mgrid[:2,:2,:2])]
# array([[0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1]])
```

Explanation: `np.mgrid` as used here creates the coordinates of the corners of a unit cube which happen to be all combinations of 0 and 1. The individual coordinates are then ravelled and joined as columns by `np.c_`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a recursive, native python (no libraries) version of it:

```
def allBinaryPossiblities(maxLength, s=""):
    if len(s) == maxLength:
        return s
    else:
        temp = allBinaryPossiblities(maxLength, s + "0") + "\n"
        temp += allBinaryPossiblities(maxLength, s + "1")
        return temp

print (allBinaryPossiblities(3))
```

It prints all possible:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```